# js: function looping through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables

I'm having a hard time answering a question and would appreciate any kind of help :

1. Declare an array named bowl set equal to the following:

   `["jelly-bean", "m&m", "m&m", "chocolate", "m&m", "jelly-bean",
   "m&m", "m&m", "jelly-bean"]`
2. Next, declare three variables: `jbOccur`, `mOccur`, `chocOccur`.  Set each equal to 0.
3. Now, declare a function named occurrence that loops through the bowl
   array, and changes the value of the three variables in step 2
   according to their corresponding occurrences in the bowl array.
   (Hint: the `jbOccur` variable should equal 3 after the occurrence
   function has run).

so far this what I have been able to produce just so you know where i'm standing... :

```js
var bowl = ["jelly-bean", "m&m", "m&m", "chocolate", "m&m", "jelly-bean", "m&m", "m&m", "jelly-bean"]

var jbOccur = 0
var mOccur = 0
var chocOccur = 0

var occurence = function (jbOccur, mOccur, choOccur){
  for (var i = 0; i < bowl.length; i++) {
    console.log(bowl[jbOccur, mOccur, chocOccur])
  }
};
```

Comment: Other than that `console.log` (edit: oops, and the function arguments and errant `;`), you're in good shape. `bowl[i]` will tell you what the value for that loop iteration is. So you can use that information to increment the relevant variable.

Comment: Your function definition is incorrect. `function (jbOccur, mOccur, choOccur);`  should be `function (jbOccur, mOccur, choOccur) { ...something...};`

Comment: **For once**, people, could we **not** hand out the code? Could we let the OP figure it out, please? So they can learn?

Comment: @Taplar: Actually, those args shouldn't be there either.

Comment: jbOccur counts number of elements in bowl array containing "j" and "b".    That's right ??

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var bowl = ["jelly-bean", "m&m", "m&m", "chocolate", "m&m", "jelly-bean", "m&m", "m&m", "jelly-bean"]

var stringOccur = function(stringArray, toFind){
  var occurance = 0;
  for (var elem in stringArray){
    if (stringArray[elem].indexOf(toFind) != -1){
      occurance++;
    }
  }
  return occurance;
}

var jbOccur = stringOccur(bowl, "jelly-bean");
var mOccur = stringOccur(bowl, "m&m");
var chocOccur = stringOccur(bowl, "chocolate");

console.log(jbOccur,mOccur,chocOccur);
```

Comment: Not very efficient since you're iterating through the array three times.

Comment: I agree. but for three variables it doesn't make much of a diffrence because you'd have to put three if statements if you use loop through only one. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Or, you could use a `switch` statement.

Comment: ty for the answer even though i don't understand the logic behind : for (var elem in stringArray){
    if (stringArray[elem].indexOf(toFind) != -1){
      occurance++;

Comment: Mottie, that would be much more efficient. I fogot about the switch statement. Thanks

Comment: Ben, can you please accept the answer. It would help for sure.